# Scrapy and networkX create a graph of domain connections between websites

Tags: python-2.7, graph, web-scraping, scrapy, networkx

Please be patient I am new to python and Stack Overflow and I apologise for any mistakes in advance

I'm trying to create a directed graph in which each node represents a domain and each edge between nodes represents the fact that the parent node has a link to the children node

(X --> Y means site X has a link to site Y and so on)

To do so I'm using scrapy to recursively extract external links from a starting url.

This is the code I have so far:

```
class LinkList(Item):
    current_url = Field()
    referring_url = Field()

class WebcrawlerSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'webcrawler'
    allowed_domains = []
    custom_settings = {
        'DEPTH_LIMIT': '5',
    }
    start_urls = ['https://www.wehiweb.com']
    response_url = ""
    rules = (
        Rule (
            SgmlLinkExtractor(
                allow=("((mailto\:|(news|(ht|f)tp(s?))\://){1}\S+)", ),),
            callback="parse_items",
            process_links="filter_links",
            follow= True),
    )

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        self.response_url = response.url
        return self.parse_items(response)

    def get_base_domain(self, url):
        base = urlparse(url).netloc
        if base.upper().startswith("WWW."):
            base = base[4:]
        elif base.upper().startswith("FTP."):
            base = base[4:]
        # drop any ports
        base = base.split(':')[0]
        return base

    def filter_links(self, links):
        baseDomain = self.get_base_domain( self.response_url)
        filteredLinks = []
        for link in links:
            if link.url.find(baseDomain) < 0:
                filteredLinks.append(link)
        return filteredLinks

    def parse_items(self, response):
        self.response_url = response.url
        sel = Selector(response)
        items = []
        item = LinkList()
        item["current_url"] = response.url
        referring_url = response.request.headers.get('Referer', None)
        item["referring_url"] = referring_url
        items.append(item)
        return items



def main():
        links = LinkList()
        crawler = WebcrawlerSpider()
        #crawler.allowed_domains.append('https://www.wehiweb.com')
        crawler.start_urls.append('https://www.wehiweb.com')
        process = CrawlerProcess()
        process.crawl(WebcrawlerSpider)
        process.start()



 if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

What I would like to do now is create a new networkX graph as explained in their docs and add each current_url as a node and have an edge from the referring_url to it.
What I am struggling with is retrieving the elements from the LinkList class and put them in a normal data structure like a list or something si that I can then call it in main() or another class and add it to the graph. 
I followed the scrapy docu but I get lost/don't understand the whole item thingy and how I can get the data from it or from the parse function

Any elucidations/help is highly appreciated

Thank you

Comment: I'm sorry I am a bit tired but I can't seem to find a difference with what I have in my editor could you point me in the right direction, please? oh I see it now sorry

Comment: should have fixed it now sorry my bad :)

Comment: Didn't know that I fixed it though thanks